# Websocket is not defined / WORKERMAN

Tags: php, веб-программирование, websocket, workerman

Делаю вебсокеты на php с workerman.. Запускается на сервере успешно, но прослушать не могу. 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Websocket is not defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        let ws=new Websocket('ws://0.0.0.0:1234');
        ws.addEventListener('message',(event) =>{
            console.log('message from server '+ event.data);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Раньше я появлялся в php index.php connections при переходе на прямую http://adress:1234, но сейчас пишет ошибку

```
400 Bad Request
Sec-WebSocket-Key not found.
This is a WebSocket service and can not be accessed via HTTP.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решил,разобрался**

```
let ws=new Websocket('ws://0.0.0.0:1234');
```

Заменил на

```
let ws=new WebSocket('ws://*айпи впс*:1234');
```